# Problem with mathematical expression annotation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I want to make the following anotation in a ggplot graph

[image]

I am triying this

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 70)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dchisq, args = list(df = 30))+
  annotate("text", x = c(7), y = c(0.019), 
           label = "P(16.791<=chi[70]^{2}<46.979)==0.95",parse = TRUE , size=4 , fontface="bold")
```

And getting the following error

```
Error in parse(text = as.character(lab)) : <text>:1:22: inesperado '<'
1: P(16.791<=chi[70]^{2}<
                         ^
```

Why the first "<=" is parsed but the second "<" doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `?plotmath` way of drawing expressions requires you to have a valid R expression. And something like

```
1 < 2 < 3
```

gives a syntax error in R. You can't have a series of inequalities like that.The easiest way around that is to force some sort of grouping in your expression with a `list()` call. For example

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 70)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dchisq, args = list(df = 30))+
  annotate("text", x = c(7), y = c(0.019), 
           label = "P(list(16.791<=chi[70]^{2})<46.979)==0.95",parse = TRUE , size=4 , fontface="bold")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This also should work:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 70)), aes(x = x)) +
stat_function(fun = dchisq, args = list(df = 30))+
annotate("text", x = 7, y = 0.019, 
         label = "paste(italic(P), \"(16.791 <=\",italic(chi)[70]^2,\"<46.979)==0.95\")",parse = TRUE , size=4 , fontface="bold")
```

Comment: Did you test this? It gets the same parsing error for me. Not sure what you think `paste()` is doing here.